# Can't take screenshot for Allure + BDD (Jbehave) (Thucydides)

Tags: bdd, jbehave, allure, serenity-bdd, thucydides

**Hello everyone.**
There is a ready project using BDD (Jbehave) (Thucydides)

There was a need to connect the Allure report to the project.
For this purpose, AllureReporter was taken from here
[allure-jbehave-reporter](https://github.com/tapack/allure-jbehave-reporter/blob/master/src/main/java/io/tapack/allure/jbehave/AllureReporter.java)
The reports are working, everything is fine.

But there is one big problem, the tests are started with the help of RemoteWebDriver on the Selenium Hub.
We need screenshots to understand what the problem is, and what happens there.

At the moment, screenshots are not taken by Allure.
That is, no screenshots are taken from the screen and are not attached.

Tried:

```java
@Attachment(value = "Page screenshot", type = "image/png")
public byte[] saveScreenshot(byte[] screenShot) {
    return screenShot; 
}
```

and

```java
public static byte[] takeScreenshot() {
    WebDriver driver = ThucydidesWebDriverSupport.getDriver();
    if (WebDriverFactory.isAlive(driver) && (driver instanceof TakesScreenshot)) {
        return ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    }
    return null;
}
```

and

```java
Allure.addAttachment()
```

That all not working for me.

This way works, takes screen shots from the screen and adds their specified folder, BUT! they are not attached to the report.

```java
@Attachment(value = "Page screenshot", type = "image/png")
public byte[] saveScreenAsImage() throws IOException {
    WebDriver driver = ThucydidesWebDriverSupport.getDriver();
    File file = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(file, new File("target/allure-results/" + file.getName()));
    return Files.toByteArray(file);
}
```

Any ideas how this can be solved?

**Thanks in advance.**

Here is POM

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-java-commons</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-generator</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <reportVersion>2.6.0</reportVersion>
        <allureDownloadUrl>https://dl.bintray.com/qameta/generic/io/qameta/allure/allure/2.6.0/allure-2.6.0.zip</allureDownloadUrl>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>allure-report</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```